# FirstOrDefault function default value

Tags: c#

I have array of objects and I would like to find index of some specific object inside this array:

```
int ix = Array.IndexOf(products, products.Where(item => item != null && item.Id == "xxx").FirstOrDefault());
```

Item with Id="xxx" doesn't exists, but the ix result is 1.
So, I guess that default for int is 1. How can I know if 1 belongs to first item or default value? It would be nice if I can set default value to -1.

At the end I have done it with findIndex method, but would like to know how to do it with indexOf method.

Comment: code does not compile.

Comment: The default value for `int` is 0.

Comment: No, default of int = 0. It probably DOES find an item in the array for which the index is 1.

Comment: `Array.IndexOf` returns `int` not an` IEnumerable<int>`. And it returns -1 if it can't find the element.

Comment: That code does not compile, there are mismatching parentheses.

Comment: You're doing `FirstOrDefault` on the resulted index, not on the list.

Comment: maybe item at index 1 of `products` collection is `null` (`FirstOrDefault` defaulf value for reference types)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you have two parts of one problem. First, you want to find a product:

```
var product = products.FirstOrDefault(item => item != null && item.Id == "xxx");
```

And when that product is found, you want to find its index in the `products` collection:

```
int index = Array.IndexOf(products, product);
```

You're halfway there using `FirstOrDefault()`. If a product with Id "xxx" does not exist, `product` will be `null`. So you can check for that and skip `IndexOf()` for `null`:

```
if (product == null)
{
    return -1;
}
else
{
    return Array.IndexOf(products, product);
}
```

The fact that your current code returns 1, means that `products[1]` is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Per Microsoft:

> Sometimes the value of default(TSource) is not the default value that you want to use if the collection contains no elements. Instead of checking the result for the unwanted default value and then changing it if necessary, you can use the DefaultIfEmpty(IEnumerable, TSource) method to specify the default value that you want to use if the collection is empty. Then, call First(IEnumerable) to obtain the first element.

However, I'm not so sure that's your issue. Your code isn't syntactically correct (you're missing a ')' somewhere), but it appears you're calling FirstOrDefault() after your Where(). This will either return an element or null. Since you said an item with id "xxx" doesn't exist, it's going to check for the index of null in your array. The default value for indexOf is (again, per Microsoft) "the lower bound of the array minus 1." This should return -1 (I'd hope) instead of 1.

Conclusion: take a better look at your code and see what's really going on. Break up this linq statement into two different parts.

```
var item = products.Where(item => item != null && item.Id == "xxx").FirstOrDefault();
int ix = Array.IndexOf(products, item);
```

Then step through your code to check the values of everything. I'm sure you will find your issue, and it won't be what you expected.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call FirstOrDefault on a struct but the default value is the same as a valid one, here's one thing you can do:

(I won't use your code as the missing parenthesis prevents from knowing what your goal is)

```
myCollection.Where(myCondition).Cast<int?>().FirstOrDefault();
```

This way, `0` would be the first correct value, and `null` would mean that there is no correct values.

Comment: This seems the most correct answer, using WHERE first

Answer (score 1):

First or default returns the first element (in this case, the first item found on the where conditions) OR, the default value.

This would return an OBJECT if conditions are met (the first object that mets the condition).

**However, if conditions aren't met, it would return null** (the default value of an OBJECT),
soo your code would be trying to find indexOf(products,null).. that would be an NullReferenceException.

**The firstOrDefault is doing his job under the OBJECT type** that is inside the array.

After this, the result is passed as parameter on the method indexOf.

"indexOf" will return the index of the first object on the "where" condition.

If not found, indexOf will return -1.

By the way, u're missing an parenthesis.